# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1048 Column 'namabank' cannot be null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got an error that says:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'namabank' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `mt_bank` (`idbank`, `namabank`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp5/htdocs/simastupen/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

i filled the form before submitting.

idbank type is int and is primary key and Auto increment, namabank type is varchar

my controller: controller/bankdatel.php

```
public function tambahbank()
    {
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('form/form_tambah_bank');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');

        $this->load->model('model_bankdatel');
        $arrdata = array(
            'idbank' => $this->input->post(''),
            'namabank' => $this->input->post('namabank')
        );

        $this->load->model('model_bankdatel');
        $this->model_bankdatel->insert($arrdata);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', "<script>alert('Data Bank Berhasil Disimpan');</script>");
        redirect('bankdatel');
    }
```

my view: view/form/form_tambah_bank.php

```
            <form action="<?php echo site_url('bankdatel/tambahbank')?>" method="post">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nama Bank: </label>
                  <input name="namabank" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="">
                </div>

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

My Model: model/model_bankdatel.php

```
    public function insert($data){
        $this->db->insert('mt_bank', $data);
    }
```

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check whether there is `$_POST` data available. If so, do the db insert, otherwise the insert query will work when each time you call the url `bankdatel/tambahbank` for load form.

```
public function tambahbank()
{

    if ($this->input->post()) { #Check post data available
        $this->load->model('model_bankdatel');
        $arrdata = array(
            'idbank' => $this->input->post(''),
            'namabank' => $this->input->post('namabank')
        );


        $this->model_bankdatel->insert($arrdata);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info', "<script>alert('Data Bank Berhasil Disimpan');</script>");
        redirect('bankdatel');
    }
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('form/form_tambah_bank');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

You should also implement [form validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller)

Answer (score -1):

The error clearly explains the problem, that namabank column cannot have null values.
Go to phpmyadmin and uncheck the null column for namabank to allow nulls.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer